# Error: el objeto tiene calificadores de tipo que no son compatibles con la función

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase Racional:

```
class Racional
{

private: 
    int m_numerador;
    int m_denominador;

public:
    Racional();
    Racional(int numerador, int denominador);
    void setNumerador(int numerador);
    void setDenominador(int denominador);
    int getNumerador();
    int getDenominador();
    bool valido();
}
```

Definición de método valido():

```
bool Racional::valido() {
if (m_denominador == 0) {
    return false;
}
else return true;
}
```

Ahora usando esta clase quiero crear una función para que me diga si el numero racional es válido:

```
bool operaciones(const Racional &r1, const Racional &r2){
//ahora cuando hago esto me salta un error:
r1.valido();
}
```

¿Podrían explicarme porqué?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de error te sale?, btw podrías simplificar la implementación del método `valido` cambiando el `if-else` por `return m_denominador != 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quiero crear una función para que me diga si el numero racional es válido:
>
> ```
> bool operaciones(const Racional &r1, const Racional &r2){
>     //ahora cuando hago esto me salta un error:
>     r1.valido();
> }
> ```
>
> ¿Podrían explicarme porqué?

El objeto `r1` es de solo lectura:

```
bool operaciones(const Racional &r1, const Racional &r2)
//               ~~~~~ <-- Está marcado como constante (sólo lectura)
```

Pero la función `Racional::valido` no es de sólo lectura:

```
class Racional
{
    // ...

    // ...
    bool valido(); // <-- función "normal".
}
```

Para solucionarlo, marca la función como constante (sólo lectura):

```
class Racional
{
    // ...

    // ...
    bool valido() const; // <-- función sólo lectura.
}
```

Recuerda marcarla también `const` en la definición.

Comment: Gracias, era eso, pero en realidad,¿no estoy modificando nada en el método válido, no?

Comment: Aunque no modifiques nada, si el método no se marca como `const` no se considerará de "*sólo lectura*".